# how to load images in server side rendering in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, server, server-side-rendering

I have this code in my server/server.js

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import express from 'express';

import App from '../src/App';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1234;
const app = express();

// ...

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
    const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html');
  
    fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
        return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
      }
  
      return res.send(
        data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`)
      );
    });
  });
  
  app.use(express.static('./build'));
  
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });
```

Also server/index.js

```
require('ignore-styles')

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
})

require('./server')
```

While running in port the **images are not loading** css is rendering in server side.

React version : 17

I have also hydrated in index.js

Any answer will be a great help .

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../images')))
```